# Find a row and its index then delete this row using index

Tags: python, pandas

I would looking for a way to basically delete, step by step, a specific row.

```
      categorie     note    nbavis  taille      nbdll       type    prix    genre
10  ART_AND_DESIGN  4.1     159     19000000    10000       Free    0       Art & Design
15  ART_AND_DESIGN  3.9     967     14000000    500000      Free    0       Art & Design
16  ART_AND_DESIGN  4.7     87510   8.7000000   5000000     Free    0       Art & Design
17  ART_AND_DESIGN  4.5     215644  25000000    50000000    Free    0       Art & Design
28  ART_AND_DESIGN  4.3     967     2.8000000   100000      Free    Everyone Art & Design
```

After deleting some row because of NaN, id's are different than index. 
So, I used :

```
app.loc[app['prix']=='Everyone',:]
```

To learn more about which row contains "Everyone" in the column "prix".

Now I would like to find the index of this row which is different from 28 (On this example, it's 4, python count from 0 right ?)

I tried :

```
app.index[app['prix'] == 'Everyone'].tolist()
```

But the result give me [28]. 
Then I tried

```
app.loc[app.index==28]
```

Same result. 
app.index[28] will told me :

```
IndexError: index 28 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

I'm pretty sure I have missed something. There are many ways to do it, but I would like to do it with this approach. For exemple `.drop` , `del` , ... 
There are many topics, but none fits with these conditions. Maybe it's not possible. How would you do this with few code lines?

Thanks

EDIT : 
There are the solutions I was looking for :

♣ Reset the Index

```
app = app.reset_index()
```

♣ Find the rows (and the index)

```
app.loc[app['prix']=='Everyone',:]
```

♣ Delete this row using the index

```
app = app.drop(4795)
```

◘ Other solution was : `app.drop([28])`
Thanks to this community. And thanks for the Edit of my topic, my english is horrible ahah.

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows that has value "Everyone" for column "prix?"

Comment: @iamchoosinganame yes ! 
And I would like to do it by using row's index wich is different than delete a row with a condition. But I'm interrested in this too ahah
My problem is that I can't find the good index, and I don't know how to delete a row using inded

Comment: does `df.drop(28)` work? also are you sure the index is a number not a string `'28'`?

Comment: it worked ! 
Thanks. I had to reset the index to find the good row, then drop it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 28 is the row identifier of the dataframe. It was originally (before you removed NA) the 28th row (29th I suppose because of the zero-based indexing). You can drop the row based on that id.

```
app.drop([28])
```

Comment: Aaah that slove my problem ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to exclude the rows where prix equals "Everyone."

```
new_df = app.loc[app['prix']!='Everyone']
```

new_df is a slice of app. You can make it a new object by using copy

```
new_df = app.loc[app['prix']!='Everyone'].copy()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment ! That's the easiest way, so that's good. But there, just to form myself, I would like to do this without creating a new data

Answer (score 0):

To drop the row inplace:

```
app.drop(app[app['prix']=='Everyone'].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for r in app.iterrows():
     if r[1]['prix']=='Everyone':
           print(r[0])
```

With iterrows() method you can print the index by r[0], and the columns will be in r[1],
if yoy want to set a column as a index you can use:

```
app.set_index("Column Name")
```